# xslt Parsing in .NET

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslcompiledtransform

Consider following snippet code for xml.

```
<rootnode>
    <child id="child1" ><![CDATA[child 1]]></child>
    <child id="child2" ><![CDATA[child 2]]></child>
    <child id="child3" ><![CDATA[child 3]]></child>
    <child id="child4" ><![CDATA[child 4]]></child>
    <child id="child5" ><![CDATA[child 5]]></child>
    <child id="child6" ><![CDATA[child 6]]></child>
    <child id="A1" ><![CDATA[A 1]]></child>
    <child id="A2" ><![CDATA[A 2]]></child>
    <child id="A3" ><![CDATA[A 3]]></child>
    <child id="A4" ><![CDATA[A 4]]></child>
    <child id="A5" ><![CDATA[A 5]]></child>
    <child id="A6" ><![CDATA[A 6]]></child>
</rootnode>
```

I want to iterate through all the child having id like 'child' using xslt.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just a note: the question is tagged as xslt-2.0 and xslcompiledtransform but xslcompiledtransform does only support XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its worth learning to not just reach for a for each loop in XSLT - this is a template matching approach to the same thing:

```
<xsl:template match="/rootnode">
    <xsl:apply-template select="child[starts-with(@id, 'child')]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <!-- Do stuff -->
</xsl:template>
```

The key bit is the xpath query in square brackets - something that ajay_whiz also suggested for the for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your xslt will be

```
<xsl:template match="/rootnode">
    <xsl:for-each select="child">
        <xsl:if test="contains(@id,'child')">
        ... do your stuff here....
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You can also use `starts-with` function see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp
for complete reference

Comment: I want to iterate only through the child node having id like 'child'
ie it should return only me the child node [child1,child2,child3,child3,child4,child5,child6]

Comment: I got your solution,
But I have more than 2000  child node. 
If there is no other way,I will go with it as "something is better than nothing"
Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Amit not sure if you could do something like <xsl:for-each select="child[contains(@id,'child')=true]">

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency you could define a key and use that e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="child" use="starts-with(@id, 'child')"/>

<xsl:template match="rootnode">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', true())">
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. But, don't recommend `for-each` instruction when there is no need.